# ASP.NET nested panel not displaying content

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm working in ASP.NET and I have a panel that has controls inside it, including a nested panel that I'm trying to add controls to in the codebehind. The code runs without error, but the nested panel controls do not appear.

HTML

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlMCSearch" runat="server">
        <fieldset>
                <div class="SEARCH_TABLE">
                ... some dropdowns here ...
                    <div class="SEARCH_ROW">
                        <div class="SEARCH_CELL CELL25">
                            <b>Departments and Areas</b>
                        </div>
                        <div class="SEARCH_CELL CELL75">
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlMCSearch_DeptArea" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:Panel>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ... two buttons ...
                </div>
       </fieldset>
</asp:Panel>
```

C# (does not appear)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            ...

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                this.loadControls();
            }
}

private void loadControls()
{
           ...
           loadDeptsAndTrackingGroups();
           ...
}

private void loadDeptsAndTrackingGroups()
{
             this.pnlMCSearch_DeptArea.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<h4>Departments and Areas</h4>")); //does not appear
             ...
}
```

Comment: At what point in the page lifecycle is this being called? Is it in an event handler?

Comment: It's called on the initial page load.

Comment: Have you viewed the page source with developer tools? It is possible that it is being added but you can't see it because of some css.

Comment: I have. It's just the empty div tag. I've been searching all over but I'm guessing maybe ASP.NET just won't let you have nested panels. I tried using <div id="someId" runat="server"> in lieu of a panel to attach my controls to but that didn't work.

Comment: I don't think nesting is the issue, I have added controls this way in the past. Do you have UpdatePanels or some sort of ajax manager on the page?

Comment: Nope. It's literally a panel that's used for searching. There's another panel below it that displays the search results.

Comment: Your code looks correct. Is perhaps some css hiding the text? Is it there in html?

Comment: No, it’s not getting sent to the server. I tried toggling the Visible attribute but it still doesn’t send the HTML.